# Exporting and Tangling simultaneously in org mode

Tags: org-mode

I am writing a literate program in Org mode, and exporting the literate document to html file after tangling.

However, after making any change to the Org file, I often have to do the export (Using `C-c C-e h h`) and tangling (`C-c C-v t`) separately. This gets 
tedious when making lots of local changes to see the effect on the code's run.

Is there a way to add a command to emacs via Elisp, to do both simultaneously. I'd like to bind this action to the simultaneous key-presses`Alt+F2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think Org has an option to `tangle-on-export`. Bu Org can evaluate code blocks on export, and one of those can do the tangling for you. I don't have the elisp skills to whip this out easily, but you'll want an elisp babel block that steps through all of the other code blocks (or a list of specific named blocks) and tangles them (or tangles them if :tangle is y and the cache is outdated, etc.)

Answer (score 8):

## Inside the current buffer

The simplest way is to create a function that does those two things for you.

When you press (`C-c C-e h h`) the function `org-html-export-to-html` is run
in the current buffer.

When you press (`C-c C-v t`) the function `org-babel-tangle` is run in the
current buffer.

Therefor you can use the following function to do both for you:

```
(defun export-tangle ()
  "Shortcut for exporting and tangling the current org-mode buffer."
  (interactive)
  (org-html-export-to-html)
  (org-babel-tangle))
```

You can then bind this function to `Alt+F2` using:

```
(add-hook
 'org-mode-hook
 (lambda ()
   (local-set-key (kbd "M-<f2>") 'export-tangle)))
```

## In a script

Sometimes you want to do this on files instead of the currently open buffer.

You can then create a similar function that opens the file for you and runs
the functions for you:

```
(defun export-tangle-file (filepath)
  "Shortcut for exporting and tangling the org-mode file at `filepath'."
  (find-file (expand-file-name filepath))
  (org-html-export-to-html)
  (org-babel-tangle)
  (kill-buffer))
```

You can then use that function in a script for example. Like this:

```
(export-tangle-file "article.org")
```

## For all files in a directory

You can even setup org-mode to publish and tangle a whole directory tree full
of org-mode files for you using the setting `org-publish-project-alist`.

Some people use this to write blogs in org-mode and then publish the whole
blog using (`C-c C-e P p`).

With `org-publish-project-alist` you create components that does different
types of publishing.

Here's an example of how you can set up copying static assets, publishing
org-mode articles and tangling org-mode articles:

```
(setq org-publish-project-alist
      '(("assets"
         :base-directory "~/blog/articles/assets/"
         :base-extension "css\\|js\\|png\\|jpg\\|gif\\|pdf"
         :publishing-directory "~/blog/output/assets/"
         :recursive t
         :publishing-function org-publish-attachment)
        ("articles"
         :base-directory "~/blog/articles/"
         :publishing-directory "~/blog/output/"
         :recursive t
         :publishing-function org-html-publish-to-html)
        ("tangles"
         :base-directory "~/blog/articles/"
         :publishing-directory "~/blog/output/tangles/"
         :recursive t
         :publishing-function org-babel-tangle-publish)
        ("notebook"
         :components ("assets" "tangles" "articles"))))
```

**Note:** `org-table-tangle-publish` will put all tangles in the root of the `publish-directory`.

So if you have setup tangling with a directory structure, it will be flattened.

I also encountered an error when the directory `publish-directory` didn't exist. 
After creating the directory it worked.

Comment: I do not know if there was a behavior change since your post but in my case org-table-tangle-publish respected the directory structure.