# Tangle only selected src blocks using org-babel on export

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I have a document with only several source code blocks that should be tangled. So the structure is:

```
    # Some main.org
    ...
    #+BEGIN_SRC awk :tangle file1.awk
    ...
    #+END_SRC awk
    ...
    ...
    #+BEGIN_SRC awk :tangle file2.awk
    #+END_SRC
    ...
```

Firstly, I have noticed that just exporting *main.org* is not goint to trigger tangling. Then, I decided to add a call to `(org-babel-tangle)` somewhere at the top of *main.org*. This call will produce *file1.awk* and *file2.awk*, but will also have an undesired side-effect of tangling the entire *main.org* file (`#+INCLUDE` directives substituted with contents of the included files, macros substituted, ...) into, well, *main.org*. How to avoid this behavior and produce only the files intended for tangling?

Comment: The key sequence `C-c C-v t` tangles the current org-file. For the combination of tangling and exporting there exists already an answer: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/29472/2370. Whereas I am willing to re-treat my close-vote if you insinst on tangling by a command in the org-buffer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exporting and Tangling simultaneously in org mode](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/24645/exporting-and-tangling-simultaneously-in-org-mode)

Comment: I don't have time now, but I'll try to edit the question later to point out that I want to do it by invoking a lisp prologue, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

The following org-file works for me with emacs 25.3.2 and org-version 9.1.6:

```
# Some main.org
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :results silent :exports results
(org-babel-tangle)
#+END_SRC
#+INCLUDE includeFile.org
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :tangle file1.el
"Contents of file1.el"
#+END_SRC

#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :tangle file2.el
"Contents of file2.el"
#+END_SRC
```

The contents of `includeFile.org` for that test is:

```
* This is includeFile.org
Some text here.
```

After export to HTML the files `file1.el` and `file2.el` are tangled and I am notified that `main.org` has changed but the contents of `main.org` remains the same after answering with <kbd>y</kbd> and also after <kbd>M-x</kbd> `revert-buffer`. The relevant content of the generated html file is:

[image: generated html file]